# PCF and servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack, cloud-foundry

Our company is using Pivotal Cloud Foundry and currently we are using WebApi for our endpoints.

I have used serviceStack in the past (although it has been a few years ago) and wanted to know if anyone is using it with PCF.
We will also use Redis and RabbitMQ services in PCF which I guess can be injected into ServiceStack.

Please let me know of your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Pivotal Cloud Foundry, but I am using ServiceStack with Redis (caching) and it works like a charm.

In your `AppHost.Configure` method you just have to register Redis like this

```
// ...
// Can be memory or redis
if (AppSettings.Get("CacheClient", "memory") == "redis")
{
    Container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
    Container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
}
else
    Container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
// ...
```

Then you can set/retrieve cache value like this

```
public static List<SupplierDeliveryState> Get(this IDbConnection db, AllSupplierDeliveryStates request)
{
    var cache = HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>();
    var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<AllSupplierDeliveryStates>(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
    lock (typeof(AllSupplierDeliveryStates))
    {
        var supplierDeliveryStates = 
cache.Get<List<SupplierDeliveryState>>(cacheKey);
        if (supplierDeliveryStates == null)
        {
            supplierDeliveryStates = db.Select<SupplierDeliveryState>().OrderBy(p => p.Label).ToList();
            cache.Set(cacheKey, supplierDeliveryStates, Settings.DefaultCacheDuration);
        }
        return supplierDeliveryStates;
    }
}
```

I was interested in using RabbitMQ but at the moment I didn't take the time to use it. I'm interested in using it to execute asynchronous actions like emails sending, users notifications sending or label printing.

Answer (score 0):

Have been using PCF for quite sometime. Also using rabbitmq.

- It’s quite straightforward to intergrate with rabbitmq if you are using from PCF marketplace.
- It also provides dashboard which is quite handy in terms of managing the queues, referring queue details etc.
- Bit of pain in terms of debugging and might cause problem if some config is missing.

Have used Redis also with PCF and dint face any challenge. You can also consider PCC (pivotal cloud cache or VMware gemfire) service available in marketplace. It’s cache service which provides good replication across DCs and high availability. Redis provides some advanced features but at cost of increased complexity.

There shouldn’t be any challenge in connecting rabbitmq or Redis if hosted outwith PCF.